# Using fscanf to read comma delimited doubles

Tags: c, csv, scanf

How would I read comma delimited doubles with no white space?

I tried the following:`fscanf(file, "%lf[^,], &x)` but it doesn't work.

The file will be in the following format:

```
1.0,2.0,4.0
3.0,6.0,1.0
```

Comment: Try `fscanf(file, "%lf,", &x)`

Comment: See also [Problems scanning into array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46761990/problems-scanning-into-array-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `[^,]` regular expression you directly use `,` .

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main(){  
FILE *fp;  
double buff[255];
int i=0;
fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");  
while(fscanf(fp, "%lf,",&buff[i++])!=EOF){  
printf("%0.1lf ", buff[i-1] );  
}  
fclose(fp);  
}
```

Comment: Note that the `!= EOF` condition is not really a good idea.  If the user types a letter instead of a comma, then your loop will continue indefinitely.  You should look for `== 1` since you scan one value at a time.